# Data Hazards in Pipeline

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

I have an assembly code look like this:

```
.data 0
.global numbers
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
.global factorials
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
.alias N 10
.program 100
li R0, numbers
li R1, factorias
li R2, N
.loop1
   li R3, (R0)
   li R4, 1
   li R5, 1
.loop2
   mult R5, R5, R4
   add R4, R4, 1
   sub R3, R3, 1
   brnz R3, loop2
   si (R1), R5
   add R0, R0, 1
   add R1, R1, 1
   sub R2, R2, 1
   brnz R2, loop1
   exit
.end
```

And i wonder which data hazards that this code contains ( WAR, WAW, RAW,..). I have found once, in line:

```
   mult R5, R5, R4
   add R4, R4, 1
```

=> it's WAR (Write After Read). Can anyone show me all the data hazards in this code, or this is the only data hazards ? ( Sorry for bad English ).

P/S: My assembly code are depends on this C algorithm

```
numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
factorials[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
N = 10 ;
for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
fact = 1;
for (j = 1 ; j < numbers[i] ; j++) {
    fact = fact * j;
}
factorials[i] = fact;
}
```

Comment: How long is the pipeline?  Presumably the loop-carried dependencies matter at least in the inner loop, when MULT reads its own output, since most CPU designs have a higher latency MULT than ADD.

Comment: Also, I assume the nested loop and array of `1..10` is an intentional anti-optimization to complicate the asm while still just storing `1! .. 10!`.  Also, this doesn't look like any compiler output I've ever seen: it optimizes by assuming `j < numbers[i]` is true before the first iteration, or that multiplying by `1` won't affect the value if it isn't, still leaving `fact = 1`.  So it's actually legal by the as-if rule, but gcc/clang wouldn't do that; they like to spend instructions on extra branching to avoid work the C source avoided.

Comment: As you have specific assembly code I guess you should add a tag for Instruction Set Architecture, if such a tag exists, otherwise mention its name in the question. This doesn't look like some of familiar ISA to me, so I can't suggest which one. `brnz` suggests LC-3, but I cannot tell for sure

Comment: Also that's not C: you're missing type declarations on everything.  https://godbolt.org/z/8G4Pbq1xG shows a version with local arrays where a compiler can optimize everything away, and with globals where we get asm a bit like this from clang for modern MIPS and GCC for MRISC (whatever that is; apparently not this.)  It's weird that this ISA uses the same mnemonic for register<-immediate as for register<-memory; most RISCs use different names.  (@AlexGuteniev: having a branch on not-equal-to-zero is common for no-FLAGS ISAs like MIPS and RISC-V, pseudo-insn for bne against the zero reg)

Comment: What is stopping you from identifying the RAW hazards in this snippet?